# Matching regular expression in an if statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have written the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Validate_Password_Hash() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.Password ~* '^[a-f0-9]{64}$')
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'The password hash is invalid! Please use SHA-256. You tried to insert: %', NEW.Password;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And I attach it to a trigger to fire before an INSERT. However, even if a provide a valid SHA-256 hash, the exception still gets raised, which implies the hash doesn't match the pattern. What could possibly be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the logic.
You are raising exception if the hash is valid.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Validate_Password_Hash() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.Password !~* '^[a-f0-9]{64}$')
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'The password hash is invalid! Please use SHA-256. You tried to insert: %', NEW.Password;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```